# Hydrangea Sao Miguel

Tags: flowers, hydrangea

My wife and I once visited Sao Miguel. Ever since my wife wants to have one of those hydrangeas (hortensias). My concerns are:

- are those hydrangeas the same as those commercially available in Europe?
- how frost hardy are the azorean hydrangeas? If they would survive in zone 7a, would they grow as large as in the azores?
- what kind of soil would I need to provide to get the same vibrant blue color?

Comment: Bringing plants from other countries is the aggravation. Import licenses and quarantine and all manner of things. Much easier to cruise over to the local garden center and get the straight info on what works in your neighborhood. Then a little googling on the stuff you asked about will give you a great start.

Comment: @Boba Fit: that's why I'm asking the question. If they are the same as those commercially available, I'd go with the local ones.

Comment: First and foremost, might I suggest you take a picture of this shrub with you to your local garden centre yourself and ask there since you have not currently stated where in Europe you live. A reputable independent garden centre would have the expert local knowledge which no online service could ever match. If I was in your situation, I would be relying on experts closer to home, wherever that is. Even in the UK, the climate can vary dramatically. Plants that thrive in Torquay, Devon would never see a winter through in York despite being about 300 miles apart.

Comment: Incidentally, the hydrangeas growing in the Azores are considered to be an invasive species, having originally been imported from Japan over 200 years ago.

Comment: @Nikki: yes, I've read about that. i have no concerns regarding this, since I live in zone 7a. Btw. the country is Hungary.